# Call servlet from another servlet form tag

Tags: java, servlets

I have a Servlet which have form tag. In this form tag I want to call another servlet.

```
out.println("<form id=\"myform\" action='/SubmitHome' method=\"post\">");
```

So when I click submit button:

```
out.println("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"assignButton\" value=\"Assign\" />
```

It is not calling the "/SubmitHome".

Any idea why is this not calling?

Comment: Is your submit button presented inside that form ??

Comment: The form `action` attribute is relative to the url's host you are presently on. Does your application have a context path? Also, have you closed your form? It's a bad idea to put HTML in Java code.

Comment: use firebug and see whats the error you r getting on console? Did you define mapping right mapping in web.xml?

Comment: This is my entry in web.xml :<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>SubmitHome</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/SubmitHome</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> . Actually this project is a restlet based web project. So I cannot able to call the jsp files. So I created these servlets. Now I am not able to submit the form from 1st servlet to another.

Comment: @vikasTheJavaDeveloper What happens when you click the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your HTML, Is your  tag is proper closing?
e.g

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You input tag is not self-closed

Answer (score 0):

Sytanx is wrong for below line (You need to complete the `println` braces:

`out.println("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"assignButton\" value=\"Assign\" />`

should be

`out.println("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"assignButton\" value=\"Assign\" />");`

Everything else is perfect and working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code to achieve your task.

Step1: Create a servlet.

```
    package org.smarttechie;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class SampleServlet1
     */
    public class SampleServlet1 extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public SampleServlet1() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<html><body>");
            out.println("<form action=\"SampleServlet2\" method=\"get\">");
            out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">");
            out.println("</form>");
            out.println("</body></html>");
        }
    }
```

Step2: Created another servlet. This will be called from the form action tag. If you observe the form action tag value, that is pointing to the 'SampleServlet2' url pattern excluding of '/'. If you want to give absolute path(Inclusive of '/'), we need to specify with context path.

```
package org.smarttechie;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class SampleServlet2
 */
public class SampleServlet2 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public SampleServlet2() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("The request is reached");
    }

}
```

Step3: The web.xml configuration is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>SampleServlet1</display-name>
    <servlet-name>SampleServlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.smarttechie.SampleServlet1</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SampleServlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SampleServlet1</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>SampleServlet2</display-name>
    <servlet-name>SampleServlet2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.smarttechie.SampleServlet2</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SampleServlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SampleServlet2</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should check url mapping in web.xml, that is the only reason form is not submitting on the desired page.